# InvalidRange error when downloading empty file from Azure File Shares with .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk

I am trying to download an empty file from an Azure File Share with the tools provided in `Azure.Storage.Files.Shares`. Downloading a file which contains more than 0 bytes works fine. However, in my integration tests, I am creating/downloading empty files. For my tests it's not a big deal to just use populated files, but it's not unreasonable that an empty file could be accidentally uploaded and chosen for download in our application. So here's the problem:

I am getting an InvalidRange error:

```
Status: 416 (The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.)
    ErrorCode: InvalidRange
    
    Content:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRange</Code><Message>The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.
    RequestId:9f04885b-401a-005e-80fa-77d94a000000
    Time:2021-07-13T15:16:59.9547272Z</Message></Error>
    
    Headers:
    Content-Range: bytes */0
    x-ms-request-id: 9f04885b-401a-005e-80fa-77d94a000000
    x-ms-client-request-id: a6ee7be7-7ae9-4587-b28c-d6a15cd499e8
    x-ms-version: 2020-08-04
    x-ms-error-code: InvalidRange
    Content-Length: 249
    Content-Type: application/xml
    Date: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 15:16:59 GMT
    Server: Windows-Azure-File/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

My download code is the code provided in [this example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme?view=azure-dotnet#download-a-file):

```
ShareFileDownloadInfo download = file.Download();
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath))
{
    download.Content.CopyTo(stream);
}
```

Again, it works fine for files that aren't empty.
[The documentation for the underlying storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file) says that 'Range' is an optional parameter that, when left empty, will download all of the file content by default. I know it's possible to do because the files are downloadable manually through the Azure Portal.

Is this a bug or is this download code incomplete?

Comment: Looks like you have discovered a bug in the SDK. Please open a new issue on the SDK's Github repository.

Comment: Thanks. Opened one here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/22616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug. Track here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/22616

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the bug to be fixed (which can take a while) you can always check the ContentLength of the file before attempting a download.

```
ShareFileProperties properties = file.GetProperties();
if (properties.ContentLength > 0)
{
    ShareFileDownloadInfo response = file.Download();
    response.Content.CopyTo(myStream);
}
```